# Wrong path in System Environment Variables - CMDER

Tags: environment-variables

I would like to ask how can I find wrong mistyped path in System Environmental Variables?

Below you can see that the CMDER application complains that this variable is not right:

*C:\Program was unexpected at this time.*

But I cannot find in my System Environmental variables. Where and how can I find it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In last row remove semicolon(;). I think that is creating a problem for you.

Comment: This is a solution. Thank you.
When normally semicolons are needed or never?